# El puerto queda ocupado al presionar CTRL + C desde la terminal linux con aplicaciones Nodejs

Tags: linux, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente problema, vez que tengo que programar en nodejs al momento de ejecutar la aplicación nodejs desde consola (node app.js) queda un puerto ocupado (ejemplo puerto:3000).. al momento de cerrar la app (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) ... el puerto sigue ocupado y al volver a ejecutar el nodejs me arroja error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` porque dice que ya existe una aplicación que utiliza dicho puerto.

Al cerrar no cierra de manera correcta y queda abierto el puerto, lo que hago es buscar el id de la app y matar el puerto con el comando `kill` pero eso quita demasiadas horas al momento de realizar un deploy

¿Existe otra forma de cerrar (de manera segura) una app en nodejs?

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar Ctrl + D?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Ctrl+D solo sirve si la aplicación lee de la entrada estándar, algo bastante poco probable. La cosa es que Ctrl+C debería funcionar, a mí jamás me ha dado problemas.

Comment: no, es como si se cerrara forzosamente sin darle tiempo para cerrar el puerto :(

Comment: igual esto le ayuda esta en ingles, pero no se si le funcionara -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675572/cant-end-node-js-application-through-ctrl-c-on-mac/27675811#27675811

Comment: Te recomiendo que una vez que ejecutes tu programa basado en nodejs en la consola, en otra consola verifiques cuantos programas nuevos están corriendo. Porque si al presionar `Ctrl + C` la aplicación termina y vuelves al shell entonces no es posible que sea la misma aplicación que detectas después en ejecución. ?Puede ser que tu aplicacion al ejecutarse haga que el SO inicie otro proceso en modo desconectado que sea el que abre el puerto y que este otro proceso sea el que se quede corriendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez presionas `ctrl + z`. Revisa bien y utiliza esto para limpiar antiguos procesos de node.

```
ps aux | awk '/node/{print$2}' | xargs kill -9
```

En tu codigo puedes usar algo como :

```
process.on('SIGHUP', () => {
  console.log('SIGHUP');
});

process.kill(process.pid,'SIGHUP')
```

Revisa la documentacion de node para poder ver todas las señales y eventos que puede manejar `process`.

Comment: luego de largas horas con mi equipo .. y analizando el error, era porque apretaba incondicionalmente ctrl + z u.u ! gracias